# How to control execution order when two events are triggered at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

This is a simple drop-down menu with `input` in HTML and pure javascript (no JQuery). I don't want to use the pre-defined HTML list with option tags because i need scroll bars, styling etc.

I hide the list `onblur` but this event gets triggered before the click on the items list. So the result is that I cant click on the items of the drop-down menu because the list gets hidden before hand.

This is the code:

```js
function showList(){
    elem = document.getElementById("list");
  elem.className = "unhidden";
}

function hideList(){
    elem = document.getElementById("list");
  elem.className = "hidden";
}

function showSuccess(){
    elem = document.getElementById("successDiv");
  elem.innerHTML = "code successful!";
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <input onfocus="showList();" onblur="hideList();"/>
    
    <div id="list" class="hidden">
      <a href="#" onclick="showSuccess();">click for success</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="successDiv">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a small delay with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) before hiding the element. In the example below i wait a 250 milliseconds before removing the class.

```js
function showList(){
  elem = document.getElementById("list");
  elem.className = "unhidden";
}

function hideList(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem = document.getElementById("list");
    elem.className = "hidden";
  }, 250); // Wait 250 milliseconds
}

function showSuccess(){
  elem = document.getElementById("successDiv");
  elem.innerHTML = "code successful!";
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <input onfocus="showList();" onblur="hideList();"/>
    
    <div id="list" class="hidden">
      <a href="#" onclick="showSuccess();">click for success</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="successDiv">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: More robust solution

You can look at the events [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) and if it is inside the list dont close it before clicking on it.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const list = document.querySelector("#list");
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#list a");
const success = document.querySelector("#successDiv");

input.addEventListener("focus", showList);
input.addEventListener("blur", hideList);

for(const listItem of listItems) {
  listItem.addEventListener("click", showSuccess);
}

function showList() {
  list.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function hideList(event) {
  if(event.relatedTarget?.parentNode !== list) {
    list.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}

function showSuccess(event) {
  success.innerHTML = "code successful!";
  
  // Remove line to keep list open
  hideList(event);
}
```

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<input id="input" />

<div id="list" class="hidden">
  <a href="#">click for success</a>
  <a href="#">click for more success</a>
  <a href="#">click for even more success</a>
</div>

<div id="successDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't work? It should print "code successful!"

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo it does work, for me it prints "code successful!". But to be sure i increased the delay, should work for you now as well.

Comment: Yes it works now, but I don't feel this is a very robust solution, wouldn't there be a better way to do it?

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo correct but it can do the trick, i more robust solution is my last edit. It makes use of the relatedTarget property from the click event.